# Using border in abline function

Tags: r, plot, colors

I would like to put a black color as a 'border' using abline function. I tried:

```
require(stats)
plot(cars)
abline(v=10, col='yellow2', lwd=2, border="black")
```

[image]

However, my yellow line does not have a black border and I got a warning and

```
Warning message:
In int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) :
  "border" is not a graphical parameter
```

Some idea how to include the border here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A line can't have a border, right? You can plot two lines instead with different weights.

```
abline(v=10, col='black', lwd=4)
abline(v=10, col='yellow2', lwd=2)
```

This can be, of course, compressed into one line of code:

```
abline(v=rep(100,2),col=c('black','yellow2'),lwd=c(4,2))
```